# Model works perfectly but GridSearch causes error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline, grid-search

While working on a project I have come across a weird error, where fitting my model works perfectly but when I apply `gridsearch` it gives me an error.

The code puts all the necessary objects created and uses them in the pipeline.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from numpy.fft import fft

class DataPreprocess(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.X_m = X.merge(y, on= ['year', 'weekofyear'])
        
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        dt = pd.to_datetime(self.X_m["week_start_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
        unix = []
        for i in dt:
            unix.append(time.mktime(i.timetuple()))
        X_t = (self.X_m).reset_index().assign(date = unix).set_index(['date'])
        
        return X_t 



class FourierComponents(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """creat features based on sin(2*pi*f*t) and cos(2*pi*f*t)"""
    def __init__(self, n=10):
        self.n = n
        
    def fit(self, X, y= None):
        self.labels = X['total_cases']
        
        self.Y_t = fft(self.labels - (self.labels).mean())
        self.Y_t = self.Y_t[:len(self.labels)//2]

        
        self.ind_max = np.abs(self.Y_t).argsort()
        
        self.t_span = len(self.labels)

        self.f = np.linspace(0, len(self.Y_t), len(self.Y_t)) / self.t_span
        
        self.f_ind = self.f[self.ind_max]
        
        self.ind = pd.RangeIndex(start = 1, stop=(len(X.index.get_level_values('date')) +1)).values.reshape(-1, 1)
    
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        
        Xt = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 2*len(self.f_ind[-self.n:])))
        
        for i, f in enumerate(self.f_ind[-self.n:]):
            Xt[:, 2*i]     = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*self.ind).reshape(-1)
            Xt[:, 2*i + 1] = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*self.ind).reshape(-1)
        
        return Xt

Unixdata = DataPreprocess()
fourier = FourierComponents()

model = Pipeline([
    ('indices', Unixdata),
    ('fourier', fourier),
    ('scalar', StandardScaler()),
    ('regressor', Ridge())
])

param_grid = {'fourier__n' : list(range(3,5)),
              'regressor__alpha' : np.logspace(1, 4, 20)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv = 5, verbose = 1, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')

grid_search.fit(sj_train_features, sj_train_labels)
```

fitting the `grid_search` here gives me this error:

```
    Fitting 5 folds for each of 40 candidates, totalling 200 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-cfce20172a59> in <module>
----> 1 grid_search.fit(sj_train_features, sj_train_labels)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1186     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1187         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1188         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1189 
   1190 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    706                               n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))
    707 
--> 708                 out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
    709                                                        X, y,
    710                                                        train=train, test=test,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1027             # remaining jobs.
   1028             self._iterating = False
-> 1029             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1030                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1031 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    845                 return False
    846             else:
--> 847                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    848                 return True
    849 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    763         with self._lock:
    764             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 765             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    766             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    767             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    558     else:
    559         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 560         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    561         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    562         if return_train_score:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    605         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    606     else:
--> 607         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    608 
    609     error_msg = ("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) "

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     85         for name, scorer in self._scorers.items():
     86             if isinstance(scorer, _BaseScorer):
---> 87                 score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator,
     88                                       *args, **kwargs)
     89             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in _score(self, method_caller, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
    210                                                  **self._kwargs)
    211         else:
--> 212             return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,
    213                                                  **self._kwargs)
    214 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, multioutput)
    176     0.85...
    177     """
--> 178     y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
    179         y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    180     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput, dtype)
     82 
     83     """
---> 84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     85     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)
     86     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [188, 748]
```

but

```
model.fit(sj_train_features, sj_train_labels)
```

fits perfectly.

Now I am wondering why and where is the mistake in the code?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

A small example (hopefully representative):

```py
sj_train_features = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1990] * 10,
    'weekofyear': np.arange(18, 28),
    'week_start_date': pd.date_range('1990-04-30', periods=10, freq='w'),
    'ndvi_ne': np.random.random(10),
    'station_precip': np.random.random(10)*10,
}).set_index(['year', 'weekofyear'])

sj_train_labels = pd.Series(np.random.random(10)*20, index=sj_train_features.index, name='total_cases')
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, and preferably a small example dataset and any missing definitions (`fft` for one).

Comment: I have edited my question by providing the full error traceback and an example of my data. And here fft is just the numpy fourier transform. which I have imported in my notebook.

Comment: @BenReiniger May I know if you are notified about my comment

Comment: I am following the question, so I got notified, and if not the @ would've done it.  But without an example dataset, I hadn't had time to play around.  I just got some time and built a small dataset that hopefully is representative enough.

Answer (score 0):

A little more than halfway through your traceback, you see a snippet from `_fit_and_score`, which indicates that the fitting has succeeded, but that scoring is what fails.  Indeed, when I call `model.predict`, I *always* get out the same length array as the training set.  When comparing that against the true labels then, the scorer correctly complains that the number of predictions does not match the number of labels.

I don't entirely understand what your `FourierComponents` is supposed to do, but I think its `transform` method needs to pay attention to the time index.